# How to run scheduler in different apps of same django project

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, scheduled-tasks

I have two apps viz: app1 and app2 in my-project. I am running a scheduled task in views.py of app1 and app2 on every month basis on different timing. But app1 is functioning properly but app2 scheduler is not calling at all.
here is my code.
app1 views.py code

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler
scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()
def start_job():
    global job
    scheduler.add_job(ampplan, 'cron', day=15, hour=18, minute=46)
    scheduler.add_job(calib, 'cron', day=27, hour=5, minute=15)
    scheduler.add_job(oildue, 'cron', day=27, hour=5, minute=30)
    scheduler.add_job(sdrmplan, 'cron', day=27, hour=5, minute=45)
    try:
        scheduler.start()
    except:
        pass
start_job()
```

app2 views.py code

```
scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()
def nlr_start_job():
    global job
    scheduler.add_job(ampplan, 'cron', day=15, hour=20, minute=0)
    scheduler.add_job(calib, 'cron', day=27, hour=6, minute=1)
    scheduler.add_job(oildue, 'cron', day=27, hour=6, minute=10)
    scheduler.add_job(sdrmplan, 'cron', day=27, hour=6, minute=20)
    try:
        scheduler.start()
    except:
        pass
nlr_start_job()
```

Comment: `from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler` is missing from app2.

Comment: @pppig But the Background scheduler is already imported. Problem is due to something  else. Like Django is taking priority from app1 views code